# What strategy can I use to improve my success with my Hammerdin?

Tags: diablo-ii

I changed my build from a Paladin using Zeal and Fanaticism (Zealot) to one using Blessed Hammer and  Concentration (Hammerdin).

I am presently at Act 5 Quest 3 in Nightmare but I find myself dying frequently while navigating the Crystaline Passage/Frozen River.

Certainly the narrow halls are a problem, but opponents which were a minor annoyance with the Zealot built are now a major problem, specifically Ghosts and any mana burn creature.

My equipment is not yet tuned to adding faster cast rate (fcr) or mana, but I did add a 20% mana regen ring that is helping.

I am trying to use hit and run in the tunnels, but to very limited success.  Since I've seen this character wipe out the Chaos Sanctuary with very little effort (but struggle with Diablo) I'm not ready to give up on the build and reroll, but I could use some ideas on getting by.

The char is currently 75 on all resists, 1850+ BH damage, 897 def (2k+ with Holy Shield), 745 life, 235 mana.  I'm using a Sureshrill Frost Flanged Mace mostly for the "Cannot be Frozen", Spirit RW Akaran Targe and Trang-Oul's Claws.  The other items are mostly there for defence bonuses or resists.

I'm playing player versus monster only (PVM) on the current ladder.

Comment: Ladder? Non-Ladder? Singleplayer?

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Ladder

Comment: Just FYI, Hammerdin is one of the most expensive builds in the game so if you're expecting an elite character, you will have to save up for much better equipment than what you're using.

Comment: @Kotsu Of course, I'm looking for insight as to whether this is a matter of not having good enough equip yet, or not being cautious enough, etc.

Comment: @Stephen, it could be a number of factors or a combination of a few, but another thing to keep in mind is that Crystalline Passage/Frozen River is a very tough area due to the Succubus/Siren mobs, as well as the Claw Vipers which can tear you to pieces if you don't avoid their attacks and kill them fast enough.

Comment: @Kotsu Add in lightning throwing upgrade ghost-type mobs packs of a dozen cold arrow skeletons and we're about there.  I've cleared through by moving slowly and carefully, drawing a few out at a time.  I wouldn't want to have done it will a Zealot though.

Comment: @Kotsu If you want to combine your "need better equip"/"it's a hard area" comments into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just FYI, Hammerdin is one of the most expensive builds in the game so if you're expecting an elite character, you will have to save up for much better equipment than what you're using. As it is also a very mana intensive build, at the very minimum you should invest in a Insight Runeword Poleaxe (Ral+Tir+Tal+Sol) for an Act 2 Mercenary, which will give you a very useful Meditation aura & also allow you to swap out some of the mana items you're currently using for ones that will increase your survivability (+HP, +Resists, +Skills, etc.). If you can't get your hands on a Heart of the Oak (best weapon for Hammerdins, hands down), some alternative cheap weapons that should not be too hard to find/trade for are the Atlantean Ancient Sword, a Suicide Branch, or a Wizardspike.

Another thing to keep in mind is that Crystalline Passage/Frozen River is a very tough area due to the Succubus/Siren mobs, as well as the Claw Vipers which can tear you to pieces if you don't avoid their attacks and kill them fast enough. I highly suggest that you navigate these areas very slowly, making sure to stay fully healed and aware of your surroundings, especially once you get to Hell. Speaking from experience, even my heavily equipped level 96 Sorceress has issues in this area, as well as my level 93 Hammerdin.